how to get only date dd-mm-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd from mui x Date Picker
using react hook form and muix date picker, need date but the issue is if i selected 27/06/2024 date then the value attribute showing 2024-06-26T18:30:00.000Z in . attaching the screen shot.
Please click on this link to see the issue

 <Controller name="dob" control={control} defautValue={null}
          render={({
                    field: { onChange, value },
                    fieldState: { error },
                  }) => (
                    <LocalizationProvider
                      dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
                      adapterLocale="pt-br"
                    >
                      <DatePicker
                        label="Data"
                        format="DD/MM/YYYY"
                        value={value}
                        control={control}
                        onChange={(event) => onChange(event)}
                        slotProps={{
                          textField: {
                            error: !!error,
                            helperText: error?.message,
                          },
                        }}
                      />
                    </LocalizationProvider>
                  )}
                />


need to using dayjs libraries and import dayjs.
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

<Controller
  name="dob"
  control={control}
  defaultValue={null}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale="pt-br">
      <DatePicker
        label="Data"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          onChange(dayjs(newValue).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            error={!!error}
            helperText={error ? error.message : null}
          />
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  )}
/>

